# Embedded JSON breaks python's JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I try to parse JSON which includes an embedded JSON model as a string property. This breaks with 
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 16 (char 17)`

```
def testJson(self):
    testJson = """{
"myModel": "{\"startDate\":\"2020-02-01T22:40:38.010Z\"}"
}"""
    myJsonDict=json.loads(testJson)
```

This JSON is valid according to https://jsonlint.com.

Why is my parsing breaking? How should I fix it?

Comment: Where does your JSON come from in the original code that motivated this question? Python string literal processing is consuming the backslashes. That only happens with string literals, not with most sources a "real" program would get JSON from.

Comment: The string is normally coming from an API request, which is itself encode using Jackson. I wanted to build unit test (without requiring the API to be up). Thanks will fix the backslashes

Comment: Alternatively you could use "raw strings" (prefix the string literal with `r`), that disables most interpretations of backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your testJson value as follows

```
`def testJson(self):
     testJson = """{
                "myModel": {\"startDate\":\"2020-02-01T22:40:38.010Z\"}
                 }"""
     myJsonDict=json.loads(testJson)`
```

Just remove the extra  quotes near the { brackets

Answer (score 1):

This json is NOT valid. It is pretend json. It is valid only at the 1st level.

Basically, this is the json you showed.

```
{"myModel": "a bunch of characters"}
```

I have encountered poorly written json data loaders, whose programmer did not use the proper json tools, but wrote their own, and to simply consider only the one level of map. This is a two level json

```
{
  "myModel": {
    "startDate":"2020-02-01T22:40:38.010Z"
  }
}
```

Which the programmer's homemade tool turned into

```
{"myModel": "{\"startDate\":\"2020-02-01T22:40:38.010Z\"}"}
```

Those backslashes are escapes, basically turning the value of "myModel" into a long string.

Such that when the loaded data reached me, I had to unescape the value (i.e. remove the backslashes) to become proper json.

Comment: This is what is expected - the myModel property should just be a bunch of chars (which happen to be parsable later as a JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` string method in order to make your json string valid:

```
def testJson(self):
    testJson = """{
"myModel": "{\"startDate\":\"2020-02-01T22:40:38.010Z\"}"
}"""
    myJsonDict=json.loads(testJson.replace("\n","").replace('\"', '"').replace('"{',"{").replace('}"',"}"))
    print(myJsonDict)
# Output:
# {'myModel': 
#      {'startDate': '2020-02-01T22:40:38.010Z'}
#   }
```